# Error in a function to print if a number is prime or not in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner to Haskell and I decided to try to write a simple function to check if a number is prime or not. Here is my attempt. Forgive me if its too shabby.

```
isPrime x = if x > 2 then (True `elem` [(x `mod` num)==0 |num<-[2..x/2]]) else if x>0 then True else False
```

Using interactive GHC, the error when I type in isPrime 7 is as follows:

```
<interactive>:75:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘isPrime’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Integral a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Integral Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
        instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
        instance Integral Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
    • In the expression: isPrime 7
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = isPrime 7

<interactive>:75:9: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from the literal ‘7’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Num a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
        instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus two others
        ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘isPrime’, namely ‘7’
      In the expression: isPrime 7
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = isPrime 7
```

Comment: Minor style comments: don't write ``True `elem` list``, use `or list` instead (also look up `any`,  `and`, `all` which are fairly common) . Also, `if cond then True else False` is a long way to write `cond`. There's nothing wrong with `if ... then ... else x>0`: here `x>0` is already the boolean value you need, so there's no need to use `if` on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what's wrong with your code:

- `mod` requires that the numbers involved be an instance of `Integral` (integers)
- `/` requires that the numbers involved be an instance of `Fractional` (floating points)

Therefore, `x` must be both `Integral` and `Fractional`, which does not exist in the Haskell standard library. Instead, you can use `div`, which is like `/` but operates on `Integral`:

```hs
isPrime x = if x > 2 then (True `elem` [(x `mod` num)==0 |num<-[2..x `div` 2]]) else if x>0 then True else False
```

However, your code also has logic errors and is much longer than it could be. First of all, you're not looking for `True` in the array, you're looking for `True` not being in the array, so you have to negate that statement. Additionally, you can just use function guards:

```hs
isPrime :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
isPrime x
    | x > 2 = all (\num -> x `mod` num /= 0) [2..x `div` 2]
    | otherwise = x > 1
```